# Citing your own published research paper in a submitted manuscript

Tags: publications, research-process, citations, peer-review, paper-submission

Is it ethical to cite your own research paper in a submitted manuscript? Are there any issues with this?

Comment: The current question is too vague for us to answer. What is the reason for citing that paper? Is it legitimately needed? Or is it just some not-too-relevant statement stuffed into the article so that a citation can be added? On top of the work by one self, did the author carefully survey other's works as well or did the author ignore them in favor of only citing the self-written works? etc.

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at the literature should reassure you that **yes, it’s quite acceptable to cite your own work,** and this is the same in every field, as far as I know. (Indeed, in the fields I know well, it’s fairly unusual to find a paper that *doesn’t* cite earlier work of the author(s), since most researchers have ongoing long-term programmes in which their later papers build on their earlier ones.)

However, as with any citation, the cited work should be pertinent to the new article.  Sometimes people cite much more of their own work than is really relevant, in order to artificially inflate the citation count for their earlier articles — and that’s certainly unethical.